# Why can't i just give a DataService object to the ctor of EntityManager

Tags: breeze

Currently I have to do this:

`var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({ dataService: ds });`

I would like to do this

`var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(ds);`

It seems too ceremonious to have to pass an explicit hash object.

Answer (score 2):

At its most basic an EntityManager can be constructed with just a service name

```
var entityManager = new EntityManager( "breeze/NorthwindIBModel");
```

This is the same as calling it with the following configuration object

```
var entityManager = new EntityManager( {serviceName: "breeze/NorthwindIBModel" });
```

Usually however, configuration objects will contain more than just the 'serviceName';

```
var metadataStore = new MetadataStore(...);
var entityManager = new EntityManager( {
    serviceName: "breeze/NorthwindIBModel", 
    metadataStore: metadataStore 
});
```

There is more information [here](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html) in Breeze API Docs.

Comment: Thanks Jay, that is useful. It would be nice to still have a convenience method for just passing the ds IF in fact that is sufficient for initialization.

Answer (score 1):

This is common practice in JS to supply only one parameter - object literal - instead of more simple params (i.e. string, number...). This object has usually default implementations in vendor's library. Default implementation is enhanced by values you specify when calling method. Often the defaults object is singleton you can redefine when starting your app/code.

And you can always create your API or wrapper around 3rd party libraries, this is good practice. Just example:

```
var myApp = function (breeze, ds) {
  function createEntityManager() {
    return breeze.EntityManager({ dataservice: ds });
  }
  return {
    createEntityManager: createEntityManager,
  }
};


myApp(breeze, ds);
var mgr = myApp.createEntityManager();
```

Comment: I agree that accepting an object with properties is common in JS, however there are plenty of examples where you can also pass a single value if that's sufficient. I am not suggesting to get rid of the object, only that there should be a convenience way to pass the DS or pass an object for cases where more than one param has to be set. I have used a similar pattern in other JS libraries.